# UIMenuBuilder not called (Catalyst)

Tags: ios, mac-catalyst, uimenubuilder

I have an iOS app (create feb 2019) which is now also available for MacOS by using Mac Catalyst.
The app works fine. I added menu functionality to the File menu with

```
override func validate(_ command: UICommand) {
}
```

Now I want to remove the Help menu.
For this I used, buildmenu in AppDelegate.

```
override func buildMenu(with builder: UIMenuBuilder) 
{
  super.buildMenu(with: builder)
  builder.remove(menu: .help)
}
```

In a newer app (Dec 2019) for Catalyst this works fine, and the code removes the menu.
In my older app, buildMenu is not called.

AppDelegate is setup as a UIResponder...

I have no idea how to make this work.
Any idea what I can try?

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was my mistake.
Once you add a Menu (UiMenuRoot) to the project, you can not use UIMenubuilder to modify the menu.

Comment: Feel free to mark your own answer as accepted. That's totally ok (stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).