# Catalyst buildMenuWithBuilder no called

Tags: objective-c, mac-catalyst

I have objective c project and I am trying to call buildMenuWithBuilder within a custom class. It's not working for me within a custom class not sure what I am doing wrong.

my .h

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface RNCatalystMenu : AppDelegate

//- (void)buildMenuWithBuilder:(id<UIMenuBuilder>)builder;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

my .m file

```
#import "RNCatalystMenu.h"

@implementation RNCatalystMenu : AppDelegate

- (void)buildMenuWithBuilder:(id<UIMenuBuilder>)builder
{
  [builder removeMenuForIdentifier:UIMenuEdit];
  [builder removeMenuForIdentifier:UIMenuFormat];
  [builder removeMenuForIdentifier:UIMenuHelp];
}

@end
```

Answer (score -1):

One common problem is `AppDelegate` not being based on `UIResponder`.

Another problem I've encountered is as documented in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61908387/21963209:

> Once you add a Menu (UIMenuRoot) to the project, you can not use UIMenuBuilder to modify the menu.